# Slow Rendering 4K Images, Fast When 2K Done First

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a fairly large scene I'm rendering with Cycles in Blender 3.4.1. If I render at 2K all is well - it takes about 15 seconds per frame. If I then switch to 4K, it takes about 60 seconds per frame, exactly as I would expect.

If I shut down and restart Blender and begin with a 4K render, it is enormously slow, taking about 15 minutes per frame. For some reason, the running the lower resolution first seems to cache some settings and speed up the higher resolution rendering that follows, while trying to do the higher resolution initially bogs the system down to the point of being unusable.

What's going on here?

Comment: If you have [persistent data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html?highlight=persistent#final-render) turned on, that could explain it.